# Getting list of urls form wikipedia page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a list of names of fortune 500 companies.
here is an example `[Abbott Laboratories,Progressive,Arrow Electronics,Kraft Heinz
Plains GP Holdings,Gilead Sciences,Mondelez International,Northrop Grumman]`

Now I want to get the complete url from Wikipedia for each element in the list.

```
for example, after searching the name on Google or Wikipedia, 
it should give me back list of all wikipedia urls like:
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbott_Laboratories (this is only one example)

Comment: And what you have so far is.... post the code. If you don't have any code, try writing some code and then post that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem is looking for possible sites and only selecting the one belonging to the company.

One somewhat wrong way would be just just appending the company name to the wiki url and hoping that it works. That results in a) it works (like Abbott Laboratories), b) it produces a page, but not the right one (Progressive, should be Progressive_Corporation) or c) it produces no result at all.

```
companies = [
    "Abbott Laboratories", "Progressive", "Arrow Electronics", "Kraft Heinz Plains GP Holdings", "Gilead Sciences",
    "Mondelez International", "Northrop Grumman"
]

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s"

for company in companies:
    print(url % company.replace(" ", "_"))
```

Another (way better) option would be using the wikipedia package (https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/) and its built-in search function. The problem of selecting the right site still remains, so you basically have to do this by hand (or create a good automatic selection like searching for the word "company")

```
companies = [
    "Abbott Laboratories", "Progressive", "Arrow Electronics", "Kraft Heinz Plains GP Holdings", "Gilead Sciences",
    "Mondelez International", "Northrop Grumman"
]

import wikipedia
for company in companies:
    options = wikipedia.search(company)
    print(company, options)
```